# htaccess redirect for certain word in urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not sure how this happens, but I have a certain string that keeps being added to my urls (e.g., foo.com/books-pdf-2012-free-**g1znpz.html**). I've looked at all the urls and they all have this bolded query.

I want to redirect any url containing that string via htaccess on my WP blog (i do think its a plugin, but I can't track which one.) I've looked around here on each thread regarding this access, and am not sure why none work.

I've started and ended with this:

```
#spam
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/g1znpz/i$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

My goal here is to rewrite everything with g1znpz to forward to google. This way it bounces them from my site, without a 404 error, and hopefully ends the onslaught. Additionally, if you have tips to locate the offending plugin, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule \bg1znpz\b /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: What is exact URL you tried and did you place this as first rule?

Comment: http://tampaflforeclosure.com/nhl-2k10-for-pc-g1znpz.html
`#spam:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^g1znpz/?$ /? [L,R=301,NC]`